# Best resource for developing JavaScript curriculum?

Tags: php, javascript, open-source

At the risk of being downvoted, I really need the community's input - I am helping put together a post-secondary quality curriculum (vocational school, not university) around open-source languages, specifically JavaScript and maybe some Ruby or PHP. There are some great trade books out there, but things get a little more limited when you need a text book with quizzes and an answer key, for example.

I believe this material exists somewhere - is there an online resource or any sort of accreditation body around JavaScript?

I realize this may be considered too 'subjective', but I am having a hard time sifting through the mountains of online JavaScript tutorials and trade books.

Comment: _"is there an online resource..."_ -- **[resource requests (where every answer is equally valid) are not quite welcome at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask "see site faq for more details")**. As far as I understand, one would rather present an **underlying problem** instead - a problem that was intended to be solved with particular resource requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for their PHP content as I've never used it, but W3Schools have a fantastic javascript section here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

The reason I like this and what would make it good for classes is that they have a "try it yourself" section on every page. This shows you the code, allows you to run it and see the result. You can then play with it and modify as you want and run again.

On its own it might not be enough, but if there will be someone to answer questions and lead the class I think this would be at least a great place to start. You could use the "try it yourself" sections as places to set assignments. E.g. this shows how to change the style of a div, now make it change the div to look like this ...